# CORS error from token endpoint when using "Auth Code Flow + PKCE"

Tags: cors, onelogin, pkce

I am trying to use the [Auth Code Flow + PKCE](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/guides/auth-flow-pkce) flow via the [redux-oidc](https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc) package.  Everything works fine up to the final POST request for an access token, when a CORS error is returned: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://subdomain.onelogin.com/oidc/2/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

From the answer to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264569/cors-issue-with-onelogin-using-custom-allowed-origin-header-1/55753945#55753945):

- "OneLogin only supports CORS for generating a session token."
- "If you must authenticate users from the client side ... Please use either OpenId Connect Implicit flow or Authorization Code flow + PKCE."

It is not clear to me how the Auth Code + PKCE flow can be used from the client side if the token endpoint does not support CORS.

Answer (score 0):

The OneLogin OpenId Connect service does not currently support CORS on the the Auth Code + PKCE flow. However there is a release planned for the last week of April 2020 that will enable CORS.